# Send Email in Java Fxml Issue

Tags: java, email, javafx, gmail

I met a problem when I try to send email in Java by using Gmail SMTP.

Once I started the email feature, there will be a email window pop out:

[image]

The user will key in the subject and email content and then send an email by clicking the `button`.

There will be two errors come out once the user clicked the `button`.

How can I fix the problem?

The errors are:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/sun/mail/handlers/handler_base, method: getTransferData signature: (Ljavax/activation/ActivationDataFlavor;Ljavax/activation/DataSource;)Ljava/lang/Object;) Incompatible argument to function
```

My code is shown below:

```
package seedu.address.ui.email;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import seedu.address.commons.core.LogsCenter;

public class EmailWindowController {
    private final Logger logger = LogsCenter.getLogger(EmailWindowController.class);

    private String password;
    private String from;
    private String to;

    @FXML
    private Button sendButton;

    @FXML
    private Label senderEmailAddress;

    @FXML
    private Label receiverEmailAddress;

    @FXML
    private TextField subjectTestField;

    @FXML
    private TextArea emailContentArea;

    @FXML
    void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

        if (event.getSource() == sendButton) {
            String subject = subjectTestField.getText();
            String content = emailContentArea.getText();
            //sendEmail(subject, content);
            sendSimpleEmail(subject, content);
        }
    }

    void initData(String from, String password, String to) {
        senderEmailAddress.setText(from);
        receiverEmailAddress.setText(to);
        this.password = password;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    private void sendSimpleEmail(String subject, String content) {
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        final String senderAddress = from;
        final String senderPassword = this.password;
        final String toAddress = this.to;

        //setup mail server

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", senderAddress);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", senderPassword);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        MimeMessage m = new MimeMessage(session);

        try {
            m.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderAddress));
            m.addRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toAddress));
            m.setSubject(subject);
            m.setText(content);

            //send mail
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, senderAddress, senderPassword);
            transport.sendMessage(m, m.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
            //sentBoolValue.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("Message sent!");

        } catch (MessagingException ae) {
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


/*
    private void sendEmail(String subject, String content) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(from, password);
            }
        });

        Message message = prepareMessage(session, from, to, subject, content);

        try {
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            logger.info(" -------- Email Send Process Failed -------- ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Message prepareMessage(Session session, String sender,
                                          String receiver, String subject,
                                          String content) {

        MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);

        try {
            // Create Email
            mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
            mimeMessage.addRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(receiver));
            mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
            mimeMessage.setText(content);

            return mimeMessage;

        } catch (MessagingException e) {

            logger.info(" -------- Email Prepare Process Failed -------- ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mimeMessage;
    }
 */
}
```

Comment: separate the mail issue from the ui - first make sure sending/receiving is working without any ui (hard-code text, properties).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the error occurs but I see two possible issue why it isn't working.

1. You ask for a authentication through SMTP

> ```
>    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
> ```

without creating a real auth like

```
Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, password);
    }
};
```

2. Why do you get your properties from System instead generating one ?

`Properties props = System.getProperties();` instead of `Properties props = new Properties();`

Comment: I did try these. But still got same errors. Headache. haha.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:*'
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:*'
```

on

```
implementation 'com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:*'
implementation 'com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:*'
```

And create app password here:

https://myaccount.google.com/security -> App passwords